# in my list view I need that when a condition is met a field is hidden: odoo

Tags: python, xml, listview, odoo-14, odoo-15

I managed to hide the content, but I need the label in the list view to be invisible in the list view as well the date the record was created

in the xml add   attrs='{"invisible":[("x_studio_selection_field_nZGcq","=","apple")]}'
but it hides only the content and not the field label

and I need both hidden if the condition is met

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not feasible to hide columns on a list view based on condition. Because there are other possibilities where other record sets meet that condition and want to display value.

Odoo will allow us to set invisible attributes in a tree view but its only impact on the value means value will be hidden, not column label/header.